# replacing `instance_exec(&Proc.new)` in Ruby 2.7

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.7

We have a bit of long-lived code in our app that sets up a "feature flag" system and looks like this:

```rb
    def configure
      Module.new do
        def self.feature(name, options = {})
          Features.current.add(name, options)
        end
        instance_exec(&Proc.new)
      end
      self
    end
```

In Ruby 2.7, that `instance_exec()` bit throws a nasty deprecation warning. How would I fix in this case? Simply replacing with `&block` as it suggests doesn't work here.

Comment: What deprecation warning? Sure would be nice to know what you're talking about. Also what does "doesn't work" mean? What is the EXACT output you receive in both instances?

Comment: Why doesn't `&block` work here?

Comment: Just curious, what is the point of this line?

Comment: @maxpleaner Presumably they're doing something like extension methods for AR associations (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Extensions), at least that's where I've done this like that. I don't get the `self` return value though. More context would be nice.

Comment: `def configure(&block)` and `instance_exec(&block)` didn't work how?

Comment: @muistooshort isn't `instance_exec(&Proc.new)` a no-op?

Comment: @maxpleaner Not really. Consider `class C1;def configure;Module.new(&Proc.new);end;end` and `class C2;def configure;Module.new do instance_exec(&Proc.new);end;end;end` and then look at `C1.new.configure() { def m;puts 'c1';end }.instance_methods` and `C2.new.configure() { def m;puts 'c2';end }.methods(false)`. Excuse the line noise, I'm trying match the question and mash it all into a comment. I still don't get why the method returns `self` or what sorts of things it is expecting in the block.

Answer (score 2):

thanks, everyone. @tadman had it right. I had replaced the `&Proc.new` with `&block` but was a dummy and didn't add that to the method definition also. Adding in both places solved the issue and eliminated the ruby 2.7 deprecation warning (about not using Proc.new to capture a block.)

The corrected code:

```rb
def configure(&block)
  Module.new do
    def self.feature(name, options = {})
      Features.current.add(name, options)
    end
    instance_exec(&block)
  end
  self
end
```